# Do I generate a new PKCE challenge every time or is it something that can be stored?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, zapier, pkce

I feel like this is probably a dumb question, but I can't find anyone who spells it out exactly.

I am working on a third party integration and am using OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grant with PKCE for authentication. Sometimes it works and sometimes it fails with a message about the PKCE challenge. From looking at logs, I can see that for the failures the PKCE challenge gets regenerated between the /authorize call and the /token call.

I've tried a variety of ways to stop it from ever re-generating the challenge in between these calls, however, I haven't found a solution yet. I have limited options and limited visibility since this is a third party integration (Zapier integration in Node), which adds to the difficulty.

So just to be sure... should I be generating this PKCE challenge each time the authentication step is run or is it something I could generate once and store in an ENV variable? Feels like the latter is improper, but asking since I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new code_verifier and code_challenge every time you start the authentication flow. Using a static value for these parameters would make your application less secure.

The purpose of the PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) is to prevent a malicious party from intercepting the authorization code and using it to request an access token. When you use unique and random code_verifier and code_challenge values for each authentication flow, it becomes much more difficult for an attacker to forge the request and obtain an access token.

By generating a new code_verifier and code_challenge for each authentication attempt, you ensure that even if an attacker intercepts an authorization code, they won't be able to exchange it for an access token without knowing the correct code_verifier. This enhances the security of your application and helps protect user data.

Here is oauth2 documentation which with code examples how to generate code challenge and code verifier on client side it can be stored in session storage or in cookies while redirection happening
https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides to PKCE:

**APPLICATION**

This sends a code_challenge on the front channel followed by a code_verifier on the back channel - see [steps 4 and 8](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) from my blog post. [Online tools](https://tonyxu-io.github.io/pkce-generator/) can be used to check these values are correctly matched.

For web clients this value is stored in either session storage or an HTTP Only cookie whole the browser redirects. Mobile clients can use memory storage. This must happen on every authentication attempt.

**AUTHORIZATIION SERVER**

The AS must store the value on the first request, then look it up on the second. This should just work out of the box for any compliant provider.

Maybe Zapier does not though, according to [this link](https://community.zapier.com/developer-discussion-13/connect-to-api-with-oauth2-using-pkce-flow-11566). Perhaps it requires you to use the older flow without PKCE but with a server side client secret?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In this case, the zapier integration is the application and okta is the auth server. With zapier I cannot guarantee that I'll be on the same node instance for each of these calls which means I can't store the challenge/verifier in memory and expect them to always match (which is what I was trying to do). Looks like they're looking into adding support for it.

Comment: Sounds like you should just get Zapier to use a client - that is pretty secure since it prevents a stolen authorization code being swapped for tokens. The multi server issue is usually dealt with by issuing an encrypted cookie and using the same decryption key on all server instances.

Answer (score 0):

I was worried about the same thing. However, I think a good solution is to make use of SessionStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) rather than LocalStorage for the PKCE code. This way if they open up multiple tabs and initiate the login flow across multiple tabs, each tab will retain its own PKCE code.